# Basic OOP & jQuery - Why am I getting TypeError?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype, typeerror

here's my basic code:

JS:

```
jQuery(function($)
{
    function MyTest() {}

    MyTest.prototype =
    {
        myMethod: function()
        {
            $(this).append("<div id='myId'></div>");
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var myTest1 = new MyTest();

        $("#anelement").click(function()
        {
            myTest1.myMethod();
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='anelement'></div>
```

Clicking on "anelement", JS console returns:

> TypeError: e is undefined ...  jquery.min.js (line 5)

...and it doesn't append "myId" - why?

Thanks

Comment: In `myMethod`, what is the context of `$(this)`?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock my goal is to append myId to anelement (on click)...

Comment: `this` inside of myMethod isn't a DOM node or a jQuery object, it's an instance of the MyTest class.

Comment: You could accept an argument into `myMethod`, and then instead of `$(this)` do `$('#'+arg).append(...);` and pass `'#anelement'` into `myMethod()`. Or, I could be mistaken on this one, you could do `myMethod($(this))`, and then do `arg.append(...)`.

Comment: @KevinB thank you. So how am I supposed to write a method that appends an element (using jQuery)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow pass the clicked element into your method. Here is one way to do it:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function MyTest() {}

    MyTest.prototype = {
        myMethod: function (el) {
            $(el).append("<div id='myId'></div>");
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myTest1 = new MyTest();

        $("#anelement").click(function () {
            myTest1.myMethod(this);
        });
    });
});
```

You could also use .call to execute your method with the given context, however you then lose access to instance methods and variables.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function MyTest() {}

    MyTest.prototype = {
        myMethod: function () {
            $(this).append("<div id='myId'></div>");
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myTest1 = new MyTest();

        $("#anelement").click(function () {
            myTest1.myMethod.call(this);
        });
    });
});
```

or simply

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function MyTest() {}

    MyTest.prototype = {
        myMethod: function () {
            $(this).append("<div id='myId'></div>");
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myTest1 = new MyTest();

        $("#anelement").click(myTest1.myMethod);
    });
});
```

Comment: It works and makes sense ;) Thank you for the complete answer.